# Appending time and date to a file (linux)

Tags: linux, date, time

I have an assignment I am doing in linux and my question is this :

Your current directory is Stenton. Append (add) the current time and date to the Holidays file.

My tree is : Stenton/gen_ed/Holidays

Anyone have any clue how this would be done? The assignment is very picky on what it accepts and will only accept the shortest possible way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo `date "+DATE: %m/%d/%y%nTIME: %H:%M:%S"` > /Stenton/gen_ed/Holidays
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: It didn't work sadly :( i feel like i have almost tried everything now lol

Comment: That's the issue, it doesn't say what is wrong, just tells me it is incorrect and to try again..

Comment: What? It asks you to try again? Where are you typing the command?

Comment: Yeah the way this assignment works is it'll ask you a question and if you don't input exactly what it wants it just says please try again. Reasons why im pulling my hair out right now.. haha

Comment: Why are you reformatting the date? shortest is just `date`. AND use `>>` to **append** per the Q. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo `date "+DATE: %m/%d/%y%nTIME: %H:%M:%S"` > /Stenton/gen_ed/Holidays

echo /Stenton/gen_ed/Holidays
```

The first command helps you to write date and time to the Holidays file

The second command is to print the content of the Holidays file

Comment: "The 2nd cmd is to print the content of the Holidays file". Did you try that? `echo` does't show file contents. For that use `cat myFile` .Why 2 answers?

Comment: @shellter echo doesn't show file content? You should give it a try

Answer (score 0):

See if this works: date >> gen_ed/Holidays